# how to store data in a large double dimension array

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to allocate memory of 10^9*10^9 in a double dimension array but this is not possible.is their any way out?

I think vector could be solution to this but i dont know how to do it.

Comment: Do you have 10^18 bytes of RAM?

Comment: Just as a sidenote, if you really need to allocate that much all at once, you're most likely doing something wrong :)

Answer (score 7):

You cannot allocate 10<sup>18</sup> bytes of memory in any computer today (that's roughly a *million terabytes*). However, if your data is mostly zeros (ie. is a sparse matrix), then you can use a different kind of data structure to store your data. It all depends on what kind of data you are storing and whether it has any redundant characteristics.

Comment: Chuck Norris can allocate it :) [no citation needed]

Comment: @NiklasB.: According to google search they have only 4 petabytes of RAM total. Which is roughly 1000 times less than a million terabytes. And even if you grab it all at once, it won't be one continuous block anyway.

Comment: @SigTerm: Of course they try to hide that from the public. Don't use Google to do research about them ;) Anyway, I guess I've been lawyered.

Comment: @NiklasB.: Wolframalpha says that estimated total size of all human knowledge is 10^19. Which is just 10 times larger than the amount OP wants to allocate. Just saying.

Comment: "all human knowledge" sounds a lot like Google to me ;) BTW, I'm not being serious.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the number of non-zero elements is much less than 10^18, you'll want to read up on [sparse arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array). In fact, it's not even a requirement that most of the elements in a sparse array be zero -- they just need to be the same. The essential idea is to keep the non-default values in a structure like a list; any values not found in the list are assumed to be the default value.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to allocate memory of 10^9*10^9 in a double dimension array but this is not possible.is their any way out?

That's way beyond current hardware capabilities, and array this big is unsuitable for any practical purpose (you're free to calculate how many thousands of years it would take to walk through every element).

You need to create "sparse" array. Store only non-zero elements in memory, provide array-like interface to access them, but internally store them in something like `std::map<std::pair<xcoord, ycoord>, value>`, return zero for all elements not in map. As long as you don't do something reckless like trying to set every element to non-zero value, this should be sufficient array replacement.

so....

What do you need that much memory for?